# How to strip html/javascript from text input in django

Tags: python, django

What is the easiest way to strip all html/javascript from a string?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Django provides an utility function to remove HTML tags:

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

my_string = '<div>Hello, world</div>'
my_string = strip_tags(my_string)
print(my_string)
# Result will be "Hello, world" without the <div> elements
```

This function used to be unsafe on older Django version (before 1.7) but nowadays it is **completely safe** to use it. [Here is](https://www.mehmetince.net/django-strip_tags-bypass-vulnerability-exploit/) an article that reviewed this issue when it was relevant.

Comment: The strip_tags does not strip html entities.

Comment: So this only strips out the tags them selves. What about actual content too?

Answer (score 54):

The [striptags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) template filter.

```
{{ value|striptags }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django 3

```
{{ the_value | striptags | safe | escape }}
```

Comment: The docs on `striptags` specifically say "NEVER apply the safe filter to a striptags output", but then you call `escape` on that...  This should just be `{{ the_value|striptags }}`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing such security concern, It was long ago and I remember that; I keep trying to chain different filters to have the desired output. regardless no user input is involved in my case to think twice of escape or safe filter usage, yet you make perfect sense if you are massaging user typed inputs, we must be more careful.

Comment: I think if you call `|escape` on the output of `|safe` it won't do anything, though.