# How to remove Ck editor tag in django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, ckeditor

I am using Django rest framework. The CkEditor tags I've used for the web appear in the API part. How do I remove these tags from the API

I had not used Ckeditor before, I was using the Django TextField field

models.py

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    ...
    lesson_content = RichTextField(
        verbose_name=_('Ders İçeriği'),
        blank=True
    )
    ...
```

seriaizer.py

```
class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = (...,'lesson_content',...)
```

output(Json Data)

```
"id":1,
"user":2,
"lesson_name":"Microprocessors","lesson_content":"/<p>Merkezi .</p>",
"lesson_notes":"<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Yazıcı, R., 1998, Mikrobilgisayar Donanım ve Yazılımı, KT&Uuml; Yayınları, Trabzon, 345 s.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Brey, B., B., 1984, Microprocessor/Hardware Interfacing and Applications, Merrill, 414 p.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Leventhal, L., A., 1979, Z80 Assebly Language Programming, Osborne/McGraw-Hill, 612 p.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Uffenbeck, J., 1985, Microcomputers and Microprocessors: The 8080, 8085, and Z80 Programming, Interfacing, and Troubleshooting, Prentice-Hall, 670 p.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>"

<p> & nbsp; </p> \ r \ n \ r \ n <p> I don't want the tags to appear
```

Comment: Can you try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977791/turn-off-enclosing-p-tags-in-ckeditor-3-0

Comment: Required tags are not displayed in html pages. Tags are displayed on the api page and on the mobile device. I want it not to appear on the mobile. I want the labels in the json data to be removed @adnan kaya

Comment: Can you try this solution ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880188/how-to-strip-html-javascript-from-text-input-in-django

Comment: @adnankaya unfortunately it did not work. Not for rest framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try overriding [`to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) method in your serializer class and use [`strip_tags`](https://gist.github.com/lambdaman2/3811586):

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags


class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
        fields = (...,'lesson_content',...)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['lesson_content'] = strip_tags(instance.lesson_content)
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you . how can I do if we want to specify two fields @wencakisa